# bootstrap-select selectpicker breaks cascading drop down lists

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, cascadingdropdown

I have created two drop down lists in an mvc application. When I select an item in the first drop down list, it calls the database and presents a specific list in the next drop down list.

List 1: Country of Birth
List 2: City of Birth (This list will change automatically when the user selects an item from the first list)

The code for these lists is something like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
    @(this.Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryOfBirth, this.Model.Countries,  new { @class = "form-control cascade-country" }))
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
    @(this.Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SearchCriteria.CityOfBirth, this.Model.ProfessionViewModel.Cities, new { @class = "form-control cascade-city" }))
</div>
```

This works perfectly. When I add 'selectpicker' to this code however...

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
    @(this.Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryOfBirth, this.Model.Countries,  new { @class = "form-control selectpicker cascade-country" }))
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
    @(this.Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SearchCriteria.CityOfBirth, this.Model.ProfessionViewModel.Cities, new { @class = "form-control selectpicker cascade-city" }))
</div>
```

...it breaks the flow. The elements have been transformed into Boostrap-Select selectpickers like intended, and the countries list works as intended (is displayed in javascript bootstrap-select format) but clicking on a country does not automatically change the cities list as it had done so previously. Instead, I have to submit the form after clicking a country to be able to see the country-specific cities in the cities list.

The original implemented javascript code for 'cascade-country' and 'cascade-cities' is as follows:

```
country dropdown js


(function($) {
    var countryDropdown = {
        init: function(action, allowAny) {
            $('.cascade-counrtry').change(function () {
                var countryId = $(this).find(":selected").val();
                var city = $('.cascade-city');

                if (countryId !== '') {
                    city.empty();
                    $.getJSON(action + '/' + countryId, function (data) {
                        var items;
                        if (allowAny)
                            items = '<option value>Any City</option>';
                        else
                            items = '<option>Select City</option>';

                        $.each(data, function (i, specification) {
                            items += "<option value='" + specification.Value + "'>" + specification.Text + "</option>";
                        });
                        city.html(items);
                        city.removeAttr('disabled');
                    });

                } else {
                    city.empty();
                    if (allowAny)
```

Now, when I click a country from the countries list, the second box disappears completely. All I have done is added 'selectpicker' to the original class. It has somehow disrupted the cascade. Is there any way to fix this?

Thankyou in advance

Comment: Which is the programming language that you are using? The new cities loaded are in the options of the select? Have you tried to execute $('.your-select').selectpicker('refresh') or $('.your-select').selectpicker('render')?